# Upgrading to a specific node js version

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to upgrade my `node` to version `14.17.1` by running:

`npm install -g node@14.17.1`

It succeeds apparently, but when I run `node -v`, I still get the old version.

Is there an extra step I should take, or am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Try using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).

Comment: You are installing a package named `node`(https://www.npmjs.com/package/node), not node itself. Download the required version for the official page and install it. Or use `nvm`

Comment: Thank you. I looked at the package page, but there is no uninstall command. How do I undeinstal this node package that I mistakenly installed?

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem?

Comment: @MarioG8 Hi Mario, I used `nvm` eventually. If you can include that in your answer, I will mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: @Joshua I added `nvm` to my answer. Thank you very much for your suggestions. ;-)Best reagrds and good luck .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is good to use a **excellent** and **proven** source. Visit official [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/) website and go to:

1. `Other Downloads`
2. `Previous Releases` - [link](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/)
3. Choose and Install `version` whatever You want, on `Operating System` You
   actually using. Good Luck ;-)

---

Or install and  use [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

To download, compile, and install the latest release of node, do this:

```
nvm install node # "node" is an alias for the latest version
```

To install a specific version of node:

```
nvm install 14.7.0 # or 16.3.0, 12.22.1, etc
```